# Imploded 2-Dimensional Return Value is Doesn't Same When Insert Into Database (Edited)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, codeigniter

So I have 2-dimensional array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => d
            [2] => c
            [3] => e
            [4] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => b
            [2] => e
            [3] => a
            [4] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => c
            [2] => b
            [3] => d
            [4] => a
        )
)
```

And I will make it into 1-Dimesional, and then implode it like this

```
a,d,c,e,b; c,b,e,a,d; e,c,b,d,a;
```

And here is my code (I using PHP and CodeIgniter as my framework) in model:

**Converting from 2D-array into 1D and turn it into string**

```
private function _randomize_answer($id)
{
    $alphabet = '';
    $answer = '';

    // Get from database
    // The result is ID question array
    $question = $this->select_temp_question($id)['question'];

    // $question output is ID questions list with semicolon as the delimeter
    // Output result is : 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; . . .
    $question = explode('; ', $question);

    // count($question) is = 50
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($question); $i++)
    {
        // Get from database
        // The output is 2-dimensional array
        $options[$i][0] = 'a' . $this->select_final_question($question[$i])['option_a'];
        $options[$i][1] = 'b' . $this->select_final_question($question[$i])['option_b'];
        $options[$i][2] = 'c' . $this->select_final_question($question[$i])['option_c'];
        $options[$i][3] = 'd' . $this->select_final_question($question[$i])['option_d'];
        $options[$i][4] = 'e' . $this->select_final_question($question[$i])['option_e'];

        // Shuffling array
        shuffle($options[$i]);

        // FOR looping, to get the first character / getting the alphabet
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($options[$i]); $j++)
        {
            $alphabet[$i][$j] = substr($options[$i][$j], 0, 1);
        }

    }

    // FOR looping, to convert from 2-dimensional array into 1-dimensional array
    // and convert again into string with comma as the glue
    // and semicolon as the delimeter per array
    // 
    // Output result is : a,d,c,e,b; c,b,e,a,d; e,c,b,d,a; . . . 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($question); $i++)
    {
        $answer .= implode(',', $alphabet[$i]) . '; ';
    }

    // To remove the end of the semicolon
    $answer = substr($answer, 0, -2);

    // Return the answer as string
    return $answer;
}
```

When I trying to echo this function into controller, the output is success with no error, like `a,d,c,e,b; c,b,e,a,d; e,c,b,d,a; . . .`

But when I try to inserting into the database, the record is just the first array, it just `a,d,c,e,b`, not all the arrays.

**Adding to database**

```
public function set_temp_question($id)
{
    $this->object = array(
        'idtemp_question'       => NULL,
        'id_exam'               => $this->_row_exam($id)->id_exam,
        'question'              => $this->_randomize_question($id),
        'answer'                => $this->_randomize_answer($id),
    );

    $this->db->insert('tbtemp_question', $this->object);
}
```

Both of these functions placed in same model file.

Comment: the code up there you posted are irrelevant, just show the part wherein the insertion kicks in, you already said that bit up there is working fine, and sidenote, just use the active record

Comment: you can `foreach` your array and create a new array to contain them using `array_push`

Comment: @Ghost When I try to echo-ing into controller is working fine, but when i try it to insert into database, the record that successful inserted into database is just the first array

Comment: So you are asking about a problem with inserting data into the db, but you don't show us that code?!

Comment: there's an easiest way to solve your problem.... you can use `insert_batch()` and simply supply the array... here's link for you to check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @Rizier123 I was put it in my `private function`

Comment: @SamTengWong Let me try it

Comment: I think you got me wrong. You say your data isn't inserted correctly in your db. But you don't show us that code which inserts the data.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I have edited

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a trivial debugging technique - just print out the SQL query and look if it actually fits the table schema.

For example, if a column looks like `answer varchar(9) not null default ''`,
you'll be limited to maximum of 9 characters per record:

```
create temporary table tmp (
  a varchar(9) not null default ''
);

insert into tmp values ('a,d,c,e,b; c,b,e,a,d; e,c,b,d,a;');

show warnings
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'a' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+

select * from tmp;
+-----------+
| a         |
+-----------+
| a,d,c,e,b |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: No I think, because my data type is `varchar(1024)` and the value input is about +-500

Comment: And how does the SQL query looks like?

Comment: I will answer but I'm sorry I'll post it later. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: What should i do to do that? Should i print_r the query or something?

Comment: Just `echo $query` within `$this->db->insert`

Comment: Ah, you're using CodeIgniter. Then it should look like `echo $this->db->last_query();` after your `$this->db->insert(...);` statement.

Comment: Hey, I put my controller only `echo $this->MyModel->set_temp_question($id);` this code, and in the inserting function, on model i added `return $this->db->last_query();` in the bottom of `$this->db->insert(...);`. When i go, the output is just like what I said in the top (just first array that could be inserted), but when I refresh the browser, the query its totally works, all the array is included and recorded into database. How it can be like that?